# dplyr::filter() for database

Tags: r, database, filter, dplyr

I am using the `dplyr::filter()` function to filter my data. I have a column called `produktslag_id` and the `format(class)` is `character`

My code as follows tries to filter out `02` AND `08` but it does not work.

```
db_sales %>%  
  filter(produktslag_id!="02" & produktslag_id!="08") %>% 
  group_by(produktslag_id) %>% 
  count()
```

I still get:

```
produktslag_id   n
<chr>    <int>

01       1330742            
02       139095         
03       636292         
04       1116240            
05       280963         
06       565081         
07       231681         
08       55696
```

any suggestions?

I did try

```
db_sales %>%
  mutate(produktslag_id=as.numeric(produktslag_id)) %>% 
  filter(produktslag_id!=02 & produktslag_id!=08)
```

and it works

but just wondering why my original code was not working and what that string for `02` and `08` could be?

Comment: The code you show should work, if that's what the codes actually are. My first thought would be to check for hidden or invisible characters.

Comment: There could be extra white space around your numbers? You could try usig `trimws()` around them

Comment: Maybe the spacing? `produktslag_id !="02"` or `produktslag_id != "02"` instead of `produktslag_id!="02"`

Answer (score 0):

It was really long space strings. 
I was using R markdown. So I did not see anything.
then I put the code in console and only select that column, I got the 02 print out like '02               ' then find the reason. 
Thank you for the comments